# What is the best windows application emulator for Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: 20.04, windows, wine, software-center, swf

I was just wondering, what may be the best emulator for windows .exe programs?

So far I was using **wine** (that was long ago few years passed).

My question mainly came from seeing that in Ubuntu Software Center, wine got some bad reviews (like 2 stars).

I mainly seek it for running .swf but .exe would be nice.

So does anyone know something new about windows emulators for linux?

Comment: VirtualBox runs Windows on Linux pretty well, but you should own a Windows license.

Comment: @C.S.Cameron There's no need to use third party products like Virtualbox, when Linux has a perfectly working native virtualization support called KVM: https://phoenixnap.com/kb/ubuntu-install-kvm

Comment: @raj a VirtualBox machine works in Windows and Linux, can I work on a KVM virtual machine in Windows? I will give KVM a try, thanks.

Comment: KVM is a Linux native feature, so no, you can't run a KVM virtual machine in Windows directly. But there are tools available to convert between different virtual machine formats, so you can probably convert a KVM virtual machine into a Virtualbox, VMWare or Hyper-V virtual machine (and in the other direction as well).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wine is not an emulator. It is a compatibility layer to run Windows programs on Linux. Some software just won't run for instance I have been trying to get Garmin Basecamp to run for years without success. WINE is free and many programs run well including Sketch Up and even WoW. If you want a professional version of WINE, you can try Crossover by Codeweavers.

Comment: Thanks for answer! So I get that Wine is still the best free windows runner on Ubuntu. Btw. I get why there's so many low votes on Ubuntu Software. A lot of people doesn't know how to run it!

Comment: Yes it takes a lot of research and patience to get the most stubborn programs to run. Hopefully more and more developers will offer Linux compatible versions as Linux becomes more popular. If you ever need more information on how to use WINE to run a Windows program, don't hesitate to ask.

Answer (score 0):

For .swf files, you can just dowload the standalone Flash player from Adobe website: https://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/debug_downloads.html (it is called "Flash Player Projector" there).

Comment: Thanks! I tried a bunch of swf games I must say it works pretty good!